# My Viewport shows weird dots in Material Preview and in Render Mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, error

So I Started modelling my car model and when I just try to preview it in Material View it keeps showing these weird black dots. It also keeps showing in render previews (Eevee & Cycles). But the rendered final output is fine, it only effects in viewport. Can anyone figure out why? [Blender 2.93.5]

Laptop Specs:
Lenovo Ideapad 300 15ISK
i3 6100U
4GB Ram
Intel(R) HD Graphics 520

Already checked the graphic drivers, everything is fine.

[image: Bug Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I've upgraded graphic card driver and it helped for a while but it's back again. I have NVIDIA TU104 [GeForce RTX 2017 SUPER) It might be something wrong with hard drive. After conducting short test with SMART (on linux) it turned out I have some problems with it:

````
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE

  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   082   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       156376305

  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0

  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0

  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   061   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       1329507
```
````